# Equivalence between the set arithmetic's and logical connectives

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I would like to know where the equivalence between the set arithmetic's (i.e. intersection, inclusion...) and the logical connectives (i.e. and, or, not...) comes from. Is it from definition, or a consequence of certain properties?

Answer (score 2):

Roughly, it is because of this:

An object $x$ is a member of the *intersection* of two sets $A$ and $B$ if and only if it is a member of $A$ *and* a member of $B$

An object $x$ is a member of the *union* of two sets $A$ and $B$ if and only if it is a member of $A$ *or* a member of $B$

An object $x$ is a member of the *complement* of a set $A$ if and only if it is *not* a member of $A$